# How to use WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT to get a second random port?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application which I start with the standard port mechanism, i.e. setting the property value `server.port` to a fixed number, e.g. 8081. I managed to expose a second/separate port in that Spring Boot application on which some other (read: internal) REST endpoints are available. Therefore, I have introduced the property `server.internalPort`.

When running a `@SpringBootTest` integration test, I can easily randomize the `server.port` value via `webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT`. But I need to randomize the value for the property `server.internalPort` somehow, too.

Is there an easy way to register a property value for randomization at test start up? E.g., my test looks something like this:

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
...
public abstract class AbstractSomethingIntegrationTest {

  @LocalServerPort
  private int port;

  @Value("${server.internalPort}")
  private int internalPort;
```

The variable `port` gets a randomized value but `internalPort` not. It gets the value I have used in the `integrationtest/resources/application.yml` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found that I can use for this specific test case the class and method `org.springframework.test.util.TestSocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort()` which [was introduced after](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28052#issuecomment-1074160853) the `SocketUtils` has been removed.

With that I've implemented a `RandomPortInitializer` like that:

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {

  // This value will be set later by the RandomPortInitializer
  @Value("${server.internalPort}")
  int internalPort;

  ...

  public static class RandomPortInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

      @Override
      public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        int randomPort = TestSocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort();
        TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(applicationContext,
              "server.internalPort=" + randomPort);
      }
    }
  ...
}
```

I use that initializer on my concrete test class where I can access the `internalPort` value.

```java
@DisplayName("Do some tests")
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {RandomPortInitializer.class})
class MyIntegrationTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {
...
```